# CI4 Attempt to read property "uri" on null

Tags: codeigniter-4

I am facing this error in my CI 4 Model (ErrorException. Attempt to read property "uri" on null)

Here's my code below.

```php
namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class scoresheet_model extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'players';
    protected $primaryKey = 'player_id';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'player_id',
        'player_firstname',
        'player_surname',
        'player_team_id',
        'player_position',
        'player_jersey_number',
        'player_is_playing',
    ];
    
    function getHomeTeam()
    {
        return $this->db->table('players')
        ->where('player_team_id=', $this->request->uri->getSegment('3'))
        ->orderby('player_jersey_number')
        ->get()
        ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Accessing the Request](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/incomingrequest.html#accessing-the-request)

> An instance of the request class already populated for you if the
> current class is a descendant of `CodeIgniter\Controller` and can be
> accessed as a class property:

> ```php
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Controllers;
>
> use CodeIgniter\Controller;
>
> class UserController extends Controller
> {
>    public function index()
>    {
>        if ($this->request->isAJAX()) {
>            // ...
>        }
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> If you are not within a controller, but still need access to the
> application’s Request object, you can get a copy of it through the
> [Services
> class](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/concepts/services.html):
>
> ```php
> <?php
>
> $request = \Config\Services::request();
> ```

##### Solution:

Instead of:❌

```php
$this->request->uri->getSegment('3')
```

Use:✅

```php
\Config\Services::request()->uri->getSegment('3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @steven7mwesigwa. You solve my issue. I found other solution but the sequence of segment number will change.

```php
<?php $uri = current_url(true); ?>
<?php echo $uri->getSegment(4); ?>
```